# remove empty directory in php

Tags: php, file

Hi when I would like to remove empty directory I got the following error:

> Warning: rmdir(): Directory not empty

**function :**

```
 if (is_dir($target)) {
            $files = glob($target . '*', GLOB_MARK); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $this->delete_files($file);
            }

            rmdir($target);

        } elseif (is_file($target)) {
             unlink($target);
        } else {
            $this->logger->error("Could not delete the folder");

        }
```

and when there are file it deletes all as it should without warning (should delete also the folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can this.

```
function delTree($dir)
{
 $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK );
 foreach( $files as $file 
 {
  if( is_dir( $file ) )
   delTree( $file );
  else
   @unlink( $file );
 }

 if( is_dir($dir) ) rmdir( $dir );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
function delete_directory($target) {
         if (is_dir($target))
           $dir_handle = opendir($target);
     if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
     while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                     unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                else
                     delete_directory($target.'/'.$file);
           }
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
     rmdir($target);
     return true;
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.